# Rails console glitches in Ubuntu with Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ubuntu

I have a default DigitalOcean VPS running ubuntu + ngnx + unicorn (from the predefined images). When I connect to the box via ssh everything works fine, until I fire `rails c`, then when I leave the console, bash starts to perform all types of glitches - half of the commands get missing letters, sometimes it shows the rails console prompt, sometimes the ubuntu one. It's basically unusable. Any idea what to poke for this problem?

I am using rails 4.1 in production mode.

Comment: I've noticed this as well in development using Ubuntu 14.04 and multiple versions of Rails. Exiting the console and starting a new one seems to not have any side effects.

Comment: It's a common issue with many Linux variants. If you exit the window & reload, it should be okay

Comment: Maybe disable `spring` on a deployment box?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not what you would like to ear, but you can try a different shell (maybe ZSH plus OhMyZsh!):

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

then

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Source:
https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh